# write a program that terminate whenever it either reads 10 number or a negative number

Tags: c++

> Write a C++ program that reads from the keyboard up to 10 numbers, using a while loop with a SENTINEL, to count and add the positive values and then display the results. Your program should terminate whenever it either reads 10 number or a negative number.  You assume at least there is one number.
>
> [image: Here is an example of input/output]

This is what I've tried, but I couldn't figure out a way to basically keep reading the inputs without submitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> until it finds a negative number or reaches the input limit (10) so it stops.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int SENTINEL = 10;
    int number;
    int count = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    cout << "enter 10 random numbers" << endl;

    while (count != SENTINEL) 
    {
        cin >> number;
        sum = sum + number;
        count++;    
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if(number < 0) break;`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solution your problem:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    const int SENTINEL = 10;
    int number;
    int count = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    cout << "enter 10 random numbers" << endl;
    while (cin >> number&&count != SENTINEL&&number>0) 
    {
        sum = sum + number;
        count++;    
    }
    cout<<sum<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that you can fix this code to correctly read up to 10 numbers by swapping the order of conditions in the while-loop: `while (count != SENTINEL && cin >> number && number > 0)`. It's also questionable whether the condition should be `number > 0` (counting 0 as a "negative number") or `number >= 0` (allowing the user to enter 0 as a value).

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int SENTINEL = 10;
    int number;
    int count = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int stop = 0;
    int aux = 0;

    cout << "enter 10 random numbers" << endl;

    while (count != SENTINEL && stop == 0) 
    {
        cin >> number;
        if(number > 0){
            sum = sum + number; 
            aux++;
        } else {
            stop = 1;
        }
        
        count++;    
    }
    
    printf("Number of positives number is %d \n", aux);
    printf("The sum of the positives numbers is %d", sum);

    return 0;
}
```